# How to assign values to multiple variables in command line with bars

Tags: shell, bash

I am essentially trying to assing certain portions of the output of a shell command to mulitple variables, but I don't know how to do that.

For simplicity's sake, assume that the command on the shell, when executes, prints

```
one two three four
```

which can be simulated with a

```
echo "one two three four"
```

(although the actual comannd is different)

Now, I'd like to assign the second and fourth word of the output (in this case *two* and *four*) to the variables *w1* and *w2*.

I thought I could use the *read* command like so:

```
echo "one two three four" | awk '{print $2 " " $4}' | read w1 w2
```

but this doesn't work, probably because the *read* command is executed in a sub-process.

So, how would I go about to achieve what I am after?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my variable being localized in one 'while read' loop, but not in another seemingly similar loop.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9954/why-is-my-variable-being-localized-in-one-while-read-loop-but-not-in-another-s)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This doesn't work because the `read` runs in a child process which cannot affect the parent's environment.

You have a few options:

You can convert your command to:

```
w1=$(echo "one two three four" | awk '{print $2}')
w2=$(echo "one two three four" | awk '{print $4}')
```

Alternatively, change IFS and use `set`:

```
OIFS="$IFS"
IFS=' '
set -- $(echo "one two three four" | awk '{print $2" "$4}')
IFS="$OIFS"
w1=$1 w2=$2
```

or a Here String:

```
read w1 w2 w3 w4 <<< "one two three four"
```

Comment: Based on the Here String: read a1 a2 a3 <<< $(echo one two three)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know about the `<<< Here String`

Comment: For safety you should use: `read -r`: `do not allow backslashes to escape any characters`

Answer (score 0):

The example get password 1 and 2 from the file password.txt

password.txt

> password1:password2:password3:column
> jnAKcxu7tyLa7DJa:nn53tSnuJJxmYbEN:97m8crLrF3ap9y9R:listpassword
>
> Jenny:37 Joun:40

```
read pass1 pass2 <<< $(awk -F: '/listpassword/{ print $1,$2; }' password.txt)
```