# Keep global variables values piping through functions

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe, control-flow

I wrote a little bash script using `sed` on some html pages to extract some urls.

To avoid each time grabbing sed results in a variable then read it again I simply made 3 functions and piped together.

```
first_function $1 | second_function | third_function
```

Let's say that:

- the first function finds item urls in a list from a given *href* (`$1`)
- the second function extracts from each of the piped urls an image `src`
- the third function assembles output HTML

at the moment I echo `$lot_url` in `second_function` so I can `read` it in `third_function` along with `$img_url` and put it in HTML.

It would be cleaner **if I could just hold it as a global variable that's accessible from** `second_function` to `third_function` but seems I can not.

This becomes more necessary as the number of values to pass between functions grows.

Here a full sample code:

```
first_function(){
    curl -s "$1" | sed -nr '
        #extract sub urls
    '
}

second_function(){
    while read lot_url; do
        echo "$lot_url"
        curl -s "$lot_url" | sed -nr '
            #extract img src
        '
    done
}

third_function(){
    while read lot_url; read img_url; do
        echo "<a href="$lot_url"><img src="$img_url" /></a>"
    done
}

first_function "$1" | second_function | third_function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two sides of a pipe are in different processes. You can't share variables between these processes. If you want to share data, you either have to pass it through the pipe, or use alternate communication channels. If you need alternate communication channels, you're above the shell's capabilities, switch to a real programming language.

Here, passing `lot_url` alongside `img_url` in the second pipe seems like a good solution to me. I'd pass them on the same line. Assuming your URLs are properly escaped, you don't need any particular quoting, you can pass them on the same line. This would have the advantage of allowing a variable number of `img_url`s in each `lot_url`.

```
second_function(){
    while read lot_url; do
        echo "$lot_url"
        curl -s "$lot_url" | sed -nr -e '
            #extract img src
        ' -e "s>^>$lot_url >"
    done
}

third_function(){
    while read lot_url img_url; do
        echo "<a href="$lot_url"><img src="$img_url" /></a>"
    done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A single while loop would do here, I think. I think it would make no difference, really, since you're calling executables every iteration anyway. In this way you *can* share the global variable you had hoped for. Like:

```
source_cmd |
    while read var
    do  fn1 "$var" |
        fn2 "$var"
    done
```

But I think better still would be to change the workflow a little - the function is nothing more than a set of shell commands based around an array. Now you're not using the array for any of them, so it should really serve to point out a common purpose for a set of commands - and the most common that I can see seems to be `curl ... | sed ...` . So I suggest you should make that a function that can accept parameters. So the result might look like this:

```
curl_sed() { url=$1 && shift
    curl -s "$url" | sed -nr "$*"
}
fn() { URL=$1 && shift
    set -- '#extract sub url sed script' \
           '#extract img src sed script'
    curl_sed "$URL" "$1" | 
        while read lot_url
        do  IFS='
';          printf '<a href="'"$lot_url"'"><img src="%s" /></a>\n' \
            $(curl_sed "$lot_url" "$2")
        done
}
```

You've already accepted Gilles's answer to this question - apparently years ago, which I didn't realize - but [here's another](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9994/52934) that demonstrates similar methodology to mine, and which I think would be better suited to this purpose.

Comment: hard to understand more than 2 years later... thanks for sharing anyway