# Count the number of characters in all files

Tags: shell-script

A file **foo** contains a list of filenames. Devise a single statement that stores in a variable **count** the total character count of the contents of these files.

Comment: StackExchange is not a place where you can find your homework assignments made for you... You ought to specify what you tried, what failed, what results you got.

Comment: We're more than happy to help, but the operative word here is help, not do your homework for you. Show us what you've got so far.

Comment: We're happy to help with specific questions about your assignment, but we don't do your assignment for you.

Comment: This was **not** an **assignment**. I was reading a book on UNIX and solving the **exercises**. I got stuck on this so asked

Comment: `xargs cat -- < file.list | wc -c` (assuming there's not file called `-` in that list and that the list is blank separated with quotes and backslash used to escape those blanks if they occur in filenames)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to do this in a single shell command.

```
<foo awk 'FILENAME=$0{while(getline<FILENAME>OUTPUT&&match($0,"$"))RSTOP-=RSTART}END{print-RSTOP}' | read count
```

This may not be the least awkward way to do it.

Be sure to tell me what your teacher thinks of it!

---

Some hints if you want to work it out:

- Yes, it does work, in any POSIX environment. But in order to see it, you may need to use the right shell.
- The choice of variable names may be a tad confusing (except when it isn't). Try renaming each of the and see which ones are significant.

Further hints:

> • The while loop condition is (getline <INPUT > OUTPUT) && match($0, /$/) — be sure to work out what the < and > operators are here.
>  • If you think this isn't assigning to count, [try in ksh or zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9954).

Answer (score 1):

Since apparently we're answering this question now.

#### Sample data

```
$ ls -1
afile1
afile2
afile3
filelist.txt

$ cat afile{1..3}
blah
blah
blah
```

#### Example

```
$ cnt=0; for i in $(< filelist.txt);do \
   let cnt="cnt+$(wc -c $i | cut -d' ' -f1)";done; echo $cnt
15
```

In its expanded form:

```
$ cnt=0;
$ for i in $(< filelist.txt);do 
    let cnt="cnt+$(wc -c $i | cut -d' ' -f1)"
  done
$ echo $cnt
```

#### The derobert's technique

One of our regulars mentioned that your instructor might have been looking for this method, which until today I was unaware of. In newer versions of the `wc` command there is a `--files0-from=` switch which can take a list of files and calculate the number of characters and the corresponding total.

The crux of the approach:

```
$ tr -s '\n' '\000' < filelist.txt | wc -c --files0-from=-
```

#### Example

```
$ tr -s '\n' '\000' < filelist.txt | wc -c --files0-from=-
5 afile1
5 afile2
5 afile3
15 total
```

This can of course be cleaned up so that the result is stored in a value. Something like this:

```
$ tr -s '\n' '\000' < filelist.txt | \
     wc -c --files0-from=- | awk '/total/ {print $1}'
15
```

And finally you can store the results in a variable like so:

```
$ cnt=$(tr -s '\n' '\000' < filelist.txt | \
     wc -c --files0-from=- | awk '/total/ {print $1}')
```

Comment: There's a stray quote character in your answer, but otherwise that's not a downright awful way.