# readarray (or pipe) issue

Tags: bash, pipe

I stuck with an strange behaviour of `readarray` command.

The `man bash` states:

```
readarray
     Read lines from the standard input into the indexed array variable array
```

but these scripts don't work (array is empty):

```
unset arr; (echo a; echo b; echo c) | readarray arr; echo ${#arr[@]}
unset arr; cat /etc/passwd | readarray arr;  echo ${#arr[@]}
```

And these work:

```
unset arr; readarray arr < /etc/passwd ;  echo ${#arr[@]}
unset arr; mkfifo /tmp/fifo; (echo a; echo b; echo c) > /tmp/fifo & mapfile arr < /tmp/fifo ; echo ${#arr[@]}
```

What wrong with pipe?

Comment: Same issue here: [Why is my variable local in one 'while read' loop, but not in another seemingly similar loop?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9954/170373) (the difference between the loop and `readarray` isn't that important).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
unset arr
printf %s\\n a b c | {
    readarray arr
    echo ${#arr[@]}
}
```

I expect it will work, but the moment you step out of that last `{` shell `; }` context at the end of the `|`pipeline there you'll lose your variable value. This is because each of the `|`separate `|` processes within a `|`pipeline is executed in a `(`subshell`)`. So your thing doesn't work for the same reason:

```
( arr=( a b c ) ) ; echo ${arr[@]}
```

...doesn't - the variable value was set in a *different* shell process than the one in which you call on it.

Answer (score 43):

To ensure the `readarray` command executes in the current shell, either use process substitution in place of the pipeline:

```
readarray -t arr < <( echo a; echo b; echo c )
```

or (if `bash` 4.2 or later) use the `lastpipe` shell option:

```
shopt -s lastpipe
( echo a; echo b; echo c ) | readarray -t arr
```

Note that this second method using `lastpipe` will not work by default in an interactive session. In that case, first run

```
set +m
```

to disable "monitor mode".

Comment: Cool. This works, but what exactly is process substitution? And what does it mean to have `< <` 2 arrows?

Comment: See the `bash` man page. In short, it's syntax for treating a pipeline as a file descriptor. `< <(...)` means to redirect input (the first `<`) from the output of the command inside `<(...)`. Similary, `> >(...)` would pass standard output to the standard input of the pipeline inside `>(...)`. You don't necessarily need to use redirection with process substitution. `cat <( echo a b c )` works as well.

Comment: Both of these options produce an undesirable result for me, where each array item retains the line endings at the end of each string. Whereas the answer by smac89 does not have this problem.

Comment: Line endings can be stripped using `readarray -t arr`. From `man bash`: `-t     Remove a trailing newline from each line read.`

Comment: I'm using `bash` 5.0.17 and this doesn't work for me. I've even checked `BASHOPTS` and it contains `lastpipe`, yet `cat myfile.txt | readarray -t arr` gives an empty `arr`, but `readarray -t arr < <(cat myfile.txt)` works correctly.

Comment: Ok, it seems that it works in a script file, but not on the command line. I don't know why that is.

Comment: @BrandonMiller, this is due to monitor mode and can be disabled with `set +m`. It is on by default in interactive sessions, but not in scripts.

Answer (score 5):

`readarray` can also read from stdin, so:

```
readarray arr <<< "$(echo a; echo b; echo c)"; echo ${#arr[@]}
```