# eval vs. pipe through bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, eval

What is the difference between using:

```
eval 'echo "foo"'
```

and

```
echo 'echo "foo"' | bash
```

is there any?

Comment: Here's another variation with slightly different behaviour as to execution environments: `( eval 'echo "foo"' )`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Short Answer

The command run by `eval` is executed in the current shell and the command piped to `bash` is executed in a sub-shell, e.g.:

```
> echo 'x=42' | bash; echo $x

> eval 'x=42'; echo $x
42
```

## Longer Answer

In the comments the claim was made that in more recent versions of `bash` (>=4.2) the first command could also have the same effect. However this does not appear to be the case.

There are actually a couple of factors which cause the piped command not to run in the current session: the pipe and the `bash` command.

For the most part, piped commands run in subshells. The Bash Manual ([Section 3.2.2: Pipelines](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pipelines)) has the following to say:

> Each command in a pipeline is executed in its own subshell (see [Command Execution Environment](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Execution-Environment)).

As pointed out in the comments, this behavior can be modified via the `lastpipe` option. The Bash Manual ([Section 4.3.2: The Shopt Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Shopt-Builtin)) has the following to say about the `lastpipe` option:

> lastpipe
>
> If set, and job control is not active, the shell runs the last command of a pipeline not executed in the background in the current shell environment.

We can verify that this is the case as follows.

First enable `lastpipe`:

```
> shopt -s lastpipe
```

Then disable job-control:

```
> set +m
```

Now execute a command which sets a variable from within a pipe:

```
> unset x
> echo x=42 | while IFS= read -r line; do eval "${line}"; done;
> echo $x
42
```

Notice that we use the `while` loop and `read` command as a work-around since the `eval` command cannot read its input from stdin (hence cannot get its input from a pipe).

This example demonstrates that the right-most command in the pipe can, in fact, be executed in the current shell. However this does not actually affect our original example. Even with `lastpipe` enabled and job-control disabled, we still get the following result when piping to `bash`:

```
> echo 'x=42' | bash; echo $x

>
```

This is because the `bash` command itself executes its input in a subshell.

Comment: that is a good observation, didn't realize that, but yeah I guess that's how pipes work

Comment: Just curious, what is the reason why you did not accept the answer?

Comment: For bash 4.2+ when running a script (or more exactly when jobcontrol is off) and shopt `lastpipe` is set and the pipeline is not backgrounded, it does run the right-hand end of the pipe in the 'top' shell not a subshell. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9954/why-is-my-variable-local-in-one-while-read-loop-but-not-in-another-seemingly and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136206/readarray-or-pipe-issue

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 The `bash` command may be executed in the top shell depending on options, but `x=42` will assuredly be run in something that can reasonably be called a subshell.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 As @hvd says, I don't think that in this case the `lastpipe` option has the effect that you're suggesting it will. Even if the pipe isn't run in a subshell the `bash` command itself launches a subshell in order to execute the command that is passed to it. In other words, the examples given in my solution have the same behavior regardless of whether or not the `lastpipe` option is enabled. I verified this myself on Bash v4.4.

Comment: @AlexanderMills Actually, the pipe isn't the only issue. The `bash` command will execute its input in a subshell regardless of whether or not a pipe is involved. See the update to my solution for more details.

Comment: nice that is good info, who's got love for the OP

Comment: igal: you're right, I spoke too fast. Sorry.