# In bash, read after a pipe is not setting values

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, read

With ksh I'm using read as a convenient way to separate values:

```
$ echo 1 2 3 4 5 | read a b dump
$ echo $b $a 
2 1
$
```

But it fails in Bash:

```
$ echo 1 2 3 4 5 | read a b dump
$ echo $b $a 
  
$
```

I didn't find a reason in the man page why it fails, any idea?

Comment: This is discussed (somewhat obscurely) in [page 024 of Greg’s Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: Also similar: [Why is my variable local in one 'while read' loop, but not in another seemingly similar loop?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9954/why-is-my-variable-local-in-one-while-read-loop-but-not-in-another-seemingly)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`bash` [runs the right-hand side of a pipeline](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pipelines) in a [subshell context](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Execution-Environment), so changes to variables (which is what `read` does) are not preserved — they die when the subshell does, at the end of the command.

Instead, you can use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution):

```
$ read a b dump < <(echo 1 2 3 4 5)
$ echo $b $a
2 1
```

In this case, `read` is running within our primary shell, and our output-producing command runs in the subshell. The `<(...)` syntax [creates](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) a subshell and connects its output to a pipe, which we redirect into the input of `read` with the ordinary [`<` operation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirecting-Input). Because `read` ran in our main shell the variables are set correctly.

As pointed out in a comment, if your goal is literally to split a string into variables somehow, you can use a [here string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings):

```
read a b dump <<<"1 2 3 4 5"
```

I assume there's more to it than that, but this is a better option if there isn't.

Comment: Or even `read a b dump <<< '1 2 3 4 5'`.

Comment: Thank you to all, btw I noted that mksh (on cygwin) is doing the same as bash.

Comment: @Michael Homer Good explanation! I found another one example that can explain that every command in pipeline run in own subshell: `cat /etc/passwd | (read -r line ; echo $line)`. But next `echo` of `$line` which is not in pipeline put nothing on screen, because value was existed just between parentheses (subshell) . Hope, It helps someone.

Answer (score 25):

This is not a `bash` bug as `POSIX` allows both `bash` and `ksh` behaviors, leading to the unfortunate discrepancy you are observing.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_12

*Additionally, each command of a multi-command pipeline is in a subshell environment; as an extension, however, any or all commands in a pipeline may be executed in the current environment. All other commands shall be executed in the current shell environment.*

However, with `bash 4.2` and newer, you can set the `lastpipe` option in non interactive scripts to get the expected result, eg:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 1 2 3 4 5 | read a b dump
echo before: $b $a 
shopt -s lastpipe
echo 1 2 3 4 5 | read a b dump
echo after: $b $a
```

Output:

```
before:
after: 2 1
```

Comment: +1 thank you for the "lastpipe" info. sorry for the delay

Comment: the problem with `lastpipe` is that it doesn't work in other shells (e.g. dash). there's basically no way to do this portable short of running everything in that subshell, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36268479/avoid-subshell-from-pipe-on-dash

Comment: @anarcat This is correct but the question asked here was about bash.

Comment: @anarcat: This may change in the future since there is a wish to change POSIX for another reason (PIPE Status) see here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/476834/read-from-stdin-works-differently-in-bash-and-zsh/476837#476837 Changing other shells is not trivial, it took me several months to rewrite the parser and interpeter on the Bourne Shell (bosh) to implement the faster behavior of the modern ksh.