# Why does ( exit 1 ) not exit the script?

Tags: shell-script, exit, subshell

I have a script, that does not exit when I want it to.

An example script with the same error is:

```
#!/bin/bash

function bla() {
    return 1
}

bla || ( echo '1' ; exit 1 )

echo '2'
```

I would assume to see the output:

```
:~$ ./test.sh
1
:~$
```

But I actually see:

```
:~$ ./test.sh
1
2
:~$
```

Does the `()` command chaining somehow create a scope? What is `exit` exiting out of, if not the script?

Comment: This calls for a single word answer: subshell

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/247187/135943

Answer (score 102, accepted):

`()` runs commands in the subshell, so by `exit` you are exiting from subshell and returning to the parent shell. Use braces `{}` if you want to run commands in the current shell.

From bash manual:

> **(list)** list is executed in a subshell environment. Variable assignments  and builtin commands that affect the shell's environment do not remain in effect after the command completes.  The  return status is the exit status of list.
>
> **{ list; }** list  is simply executed in the current shell environment. list must be terminated with a newline or semicolon.  This is known as a group command.  The return  status  is the exit status of list.  Note that unlike the metacharacters ( and ), { and } are reserved words and must occur where a reserved word is  permitted  to  be recognized.  Since they do not cause a word break, they must be separated from list by whitespace or another shell metacharacter.

It's worth mentioning that the shell syntax is quite consistent and the subshell participates also in the other `()` constructs like command substitution (also with the old-style `` `..` `` syntax) or process substitution, so the following won't exit from the current shell either:

```
echo $(exit)
cat <(exit)
```

---

While it may be obvious that subshells are involved when commands are placed explicitly inside `()`, the less visible fact is that they are also spawned in these other structures:

- command started in the background

  ```
  exit &
  ```

  doesn't exit the current shell because (after `man bash`)

  > If a command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell executes the command in the background in a subshell.  The shell does not wait for the command to finish, and the return status is 0.
- the pipeline

  ```
  exit | echo foo
  ```

  still exits only from the subshell.

  However different shells behave differently in this regard. For example `bash` puts all components of the pipeline into separate subshells (unless you use the `lastpipe` option in invocations where job control is not enabled), but AT&T `ksh` and `zsh` run the last part inside the current shell (both behaviours are allowed by POSIX). Thus

  ```
  exit | exit | exit
  ```

  does basically nothing in bash, but exits from the zsh because of **the last** `exit`.
- `coproc exit` also runs `exit` in a subshell.

Comment: Ah. Now to find all the places, where my predecessor used the wrong braces. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Take careful note of the spacing in the man page: `{` and `}` are not syntax, they are reserved words and must be surrounded by spaces, and the list must end with a command terminator (semicolon, newline, ampersand)

Comment: Out of interest, does this tend to actually be another process or just a separate environment in an internal stack? I use () a lot for isolating chdirs, and must have been lucky with my use of $$ etc if the former.

Comment: @DanSheppard It is another process, but `(echo $$)` prints parent shell id because `$$` is expanded even before subshell is created. In fact printing subshell process id could be tricky, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119885/how-to-get-the-process-id-of-a-bash-subprocess-on-command-line

Comment: @jimmij, How can it be that `$$` is expanded before the subshell is created, and yet `$BASHPID` shows the correct value for a subshell?

Comment: @Wildcard Because $BASHPID is special variable as manual explains: `Expands to the process ID of the current bash process.  This differs from  $$ under certain circumstances, such as subshells that do not require bash to be re-initialized.`

Comment: bash 4.2 up has shopt lastpipe to change the pipe case in a script (to be exact when jobcontrol off): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/143958/in-bash-read-after-a-pipe-is-not-setting-values

Answer (score 17):

Executing the `exit` in a subshell is one pitfall:

```
#!/bin/bash
function calc { echo 42; exit 1; }
echo $(calc)
```

The script prints 42, exits from the **subshell** with return code `1`, and continues with the script. Even replacing the call by `echo $(CALC) || exit 1` does not help because the return code of `echo` is 0 regardless of the return code of `calc`. And `calc` is executed prior to `echo`.

Even more puzzling is thwarting the effect of `exit` by wrapping it into `local` builtin like in the following script. I stumbled over the problem when I wrote a function to verify an input value. Example:

I want to create a file named "year month day.log", i.e., `20141211.log` for today. The date is input by a user who may fail to provide a reasonable value. Therefore, in my function `fname` I check the return value of `date` to verify the validity of the user input:

```
#!/bin/bash

doit ()
    {
    local FNAME=$(fname "$1") || exit 1
    touch "${FNAME}"
    }

fname ()
    {
    date +"%Y%m%d.log" -d"$1" 2>/dev/null
    if [ "$?" != 0 ] ; then
        echo "fname reports \"Illegal Date\"" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
    }

doit "$1"
```

Looks good. Let the script be named `s.sh`. If the user calls the script with `./s.sh "Thu Dec 11 20:45:49 CET 2014"`, the file `20141211.log` is created. If, however, the user types `./s.sh "Thu hec 11 20:45:49 CET 2014"`, then the script outputs:

```
fname reports "Illegal Date"
touch: cannot touch ‘’: No such file or directory
```

The line `fname…` says that the bad input data has been detected in the subshell. But the `exit 1` at the end of the `local …` line is never triggered because the `local` directive always return `0`. This is because `local` is executed **after** `$(fname)` and thus overwrites its return code. And because of that, the script continues and invokes `touch` with an empty parameter. This example is simple but the behavior of bash can be quite confusing in a real application. I know, real programmers don't use locals.☺

To make it clear: Without the `local`, the script aborts as expected when an invalid date is entered.

The fix is to split the line like

```
local FNAME
FNAME=$(fname "$1") || exit 1
```

The strange behavior conforms to the documentation of `local` within the man page of bash: "The return status is 0 unless local is used outside a function, an invalid name is supplied, or name is a readonly variable."

Though not being a bug I feel that the behaviour of bash is counterintuitive. I am aware of the sequence of execution, `local` should not mask a broken assignment, nevertheless.

My initial answer contained some inaccurancies. After a revealing and in-depth discussion with mikeserv (thank you for that) I went for fixing them.

Comment: @mikeserv: I added an example to show the relevance.

Comment: @mikeserv: Yes, you're right. Even terser. But the pitfall is still there.

Comment: @mikeserv: Sorry, my example was broken. I'd forgotten the test in `doit()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19419/discussion-between-hermannk-and-mikeserv).

Answer (score 6):

The actual solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

function bla() {
    return 1
}

bla || { echo '1'; exit 1; }

echo '2'
```

The error grouping will only execute if `bla` returns an error status, and `exit` is not in a subshell so the whole script stops.

Answer (score 1):

The brackets start a **subshell** and the exit only exits that subshell.

You can read the exitcode with `$?` and add this in your script to exit the script if the subshell was exited:

```
#!/bin/bash

function bla() {
    return 1
}

bla || ( echo '1' ; exit 1 )

exitcode=$?
if [ $exitcode != 0 ]; then exit $exitcode; fi

echo '2'
```