# Weird behavior in zsh random generator

Tags: zsh, command-substitution, random, subshell

I have this script to generate $1 digit(s) of mixed random char from the defined charlists as arrays.

```
#!/bin/bash

charlist1=(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z)
charlist2=(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
charlists=(${charlist1[*]} ${charlist2[*]})

i="1"
while [ $i -le $1 ]; do
    out=$out`echo -n ${charlists[$(($RANDOM % ${#charlists[*]}))]}`
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
done

echo $out
```

It runs fine in bash, but then if I invoke it with zsh by `zsh that_script_above.sh 6` it just generates 6 digit of some same character like this:

```
>>> zsh that_script_above.sh 6
llllll
>>> zsh that_script_above.sh 6
bbbbbb
```

And if I modified that script to be like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

charlist1=(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z)
charlist2=(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
charlists=(${charlist1[*]} ${charlist2[*]})

i="1"
while [ $i -le $1 ]; do

    echo -n ${charlists[$(($RANDOM % ${#charlists[*]}))]}

    i=$(( i + 1 ))
done

echo
```

it works well as I desired for both `bash` and `zsh`.

So, here is my questions:

1. Can someone explain to me about my problem with zsh bash behaviour stated above?
2. And how can I use for loop in bash with customizable variable? because it seems `for i in {1..$1}` doesn't work in bash.

Comment: Beware `bash`/`zsh`/`ksh` pseudo random number generators are not cryptographically secure, they shouldn't be used to generate secrets.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas actually it is just to generate unique folder name, by iterating it and comparing with array generated by command `ls` in some folder, i can get unique id...

Comment: Many systems have a `mktemp` command just for that: `dir=$(mktemp -dp . myprefixXXXXXX)` would create a (private) unique directory in the current directory with that template and store it in `$dir`. *Comparing with `ls`* is racy. It's better to attempt the mkdirs until it succeeds. Beware of symlinks as well! All those issues are handled properly by `mktemp`.

Comment: Whoaaa that's new... never thought about symlinks... thanks pal

Comment: You could use a "C-style" for loop in bash: `for ((i=1; i<="$1"; i++)); do ...` -- see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Looping-Constructs

Answer (score 10):

Q1. Command substitution (backticks) uses a subshell, and in zsh a subshell's RNG state not reseeded. Since you repeatedly create a new subshell without using `$RANDOM` in the parent, you  get the same value in each subshell. See:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32577117/references-to-random-in-subshells-all-returning-identical-values
https://superuser.com/questions/1210435/different-behavior-of-in-zsh-and-bash-functions

You don't need the command-substitution and echo, and you also don't need the `$((..))` because an array subscript is already evaluated as an arithmetic expression, but you do need +1 because zsh arrays are 1-origin (you were lucky you didn't happen to hit 0):

```
 out=$out${charlists[ $RANDOM % ${#charlists[*]} + 1 ]}
```

Aside: even if you did need an `echo` in command substitution you don't need `-n` because command substitution itself removes any trailing newline(s) from the data captured and substituted.

Q2. bash does brace-expansion before it does parameter-expansion (and command and arithmetic substitution/expansions), but zsh (and ksh) does it after. You can use `for i in $(seq 1 $1)` or yucky but builtin `for i in $(eval "echo {1..$n}")`

Comment: Whooa thanks so much. Sorry if I asked question that apparently had already been asked. I've googling with irrelevant keyword, thanks for referring the link. And the fact that command in backticks forking a subshell is so new to me, probably the best thin I learn today. But what about `$(eval (echo))`? Does it uses subshell?

Comment: Yes. `$(...)` is a subshell. `<(...)` is a subshell.  All of the commands in a pipeline except the first or last are in subshells. (In bash, `command | while read; do` runs the `while` loop in a subshell, so it can have no lasting effects. ksh and zsh instead run the `while` in the current shell, so `command` is the one that can't have lasting effects.)

Comment: @MarkReed: subshells for a pipeline is not relevant to this Q, but we have lots of other Qs or As on them. All nonlast parts are _always_ subshells, and in bash the last part is sometimes not a subshell. See to start https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/677519/ https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440088/ https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442215/ https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/143958/ https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/172541/ https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9954/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746553/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686872/