# Why a bash array remains empty if I pipe the result of a for loop, used to populate it, into zenity --progress?

Tags: bash, pipe, bash-array

I have an array with some data:

`array1=( AAA BBB CCC DDD )`

I want to populate an array of results from calling a certain API with the data in `array1` and at the same time I want to show the progress with `zenity`. So I though about doing this:

```
i=0
prog=0

for c in ${array1[@]}; do
  echo $prog  #updates the text
  echo "# $c" #updates the percentage

  data_array[$i]=$(curl -s "https://hub.dummyapis.com/products?noofRecords=4&idStarts=1001&useless=$c" | jq .[$i].id | bc)

  (( prog=prog+30 ))
  (( i++ ))
done | zenity \
    --progress \
    --title="Title" \
    --text="Text" \
    --percentage=0 \
    --auto-close \
    --auto-kill
```

The problem is that the `data_array` remains empty.

On the other hand, it gets populated if I omit the pipe to the `zenity` command. If I understood correctly, it's because the pipe it's spawning a new subprocess, thus the `data_array` is empty there.

I also tried using this sintax, but with same results:

```
zenity \
    --progress \
    --title="Title" \
    --text="Text" \
    --percentage=0 \
    --auto-close \
    --auto-kill < <(
for c in ${array1[@]}; do
  echo $prog
  echo "# $c"

  data_array[$i]=$(curl -s "https://hub.dummyapis.com/products?noofRecords=4&idStarts=1001&useless=$c" | jq .[$i].id | bc)

  (( prog=prog+30 ))
  (( i++ ))
done)
```

What can I do?

Comment: In both cases, data_array is in the scope of a sub-process, not the outer process. The two parts of a pipeline run in sub-processes. The $(..) runs in a sub-process.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant nitpick: the _first_ part (or in general all but the last part) of a pipeline always runs in subshell(s); the last part in general _may_ run in a subshell or the main shell, and for bash it runs in the main shell if job control is off and shopt LASTPIPE is on. That makes a difference for (fairly numerous) questions of the form `something | while read stuff; do set some vars; done`, but not this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parts of a pipeline run in subshells. (In Bash, you can enable the `lastpipe` option to have the last part run in the main shell, but that doesn't help here.) Process substitutions also run in subshells, but they don't force main part to do so too.

Put  `zenity` in a process substitution instead and keep the `for` in the main shell:

```
for c in ${array1[@]}; do
  ...
  data_array[$i]=...
  ...
done > >( zenity \
    --progress \
    --title="Title" \
    --text="Text" \
    --percentage=0 \
    --auto-close \
    --auto-kill )
```

Comment: Yep, this is it... I kinda recognized I needed a process substitution, but I swapped the two parts of the script   ':D

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility: Replace in your first example

```
data_array[$i]=$(curl ... | jq ... | bc)
```

with

```
curl ... | jq ... | bc >> /tmp/so-q
```

and add after your code:

```
mapfile -t data_array < /tmp/so-q
rm /tmp/so-q
declare -p data_array
```

---

To create secure temporary files you can use mktemp. See `man mktemp`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not the most elegant solution, but it works.

It relies on `tee` for the output of the loop to be written to a file and piped into `zenity` at the same time.

Using the dummy code above, it become:

```
array1=( AAA BBB CCC DDD )

curl_cmd() {
  curl -s "https://hub.dummyapis.com/products?noofRecords=4&idStarts=1001&useless=$1" | jq .[$2].id | bc
}

i=0
prog=0

for c in ${array1[@]}; do
  #updates the text
  echo $prog
  #updates the percentage
  echo "# $c"

  #echo the data I'm interested in, 
  #with a @ for later reference
  echo "@ $(curl_cmd $c $i)" 

  (( prog=prog+30 ))
  (( i++ ))
done | tee >(zenity \
    --progress \
    --title="Title" \
    --text="Text" \
    --percentage=0 \
    --auto-close \
    --auto-kill) > /tmp/so-q

data_array=( $(grep @ /tmp/so-q | cut -c 2-) )
```

Now the `data_array` is finally populated

```
~ $ echo ${data_array[@]}
1001 1002 1003 1004
```