Unexpected subshell
I was writing a script which takes a JSON array as an input and applied a transformation to the data before appending the output to a variable. This did not behave as expected. A minimal version is shown below:
CONFIG_JSON="sample.json"
CMKVALUES="INIT"

function append()
{
        local s
        s="$1"
        CMKVALUES="$CMKVALUES,$s"
}

function mainloop()
{
 # process the output
    jq -c '.[]' "$CONFIG_JSON" | while read i; do
        NAME="$( echo $i | jq -r .name)"
        echo "read $NAME"
        [ "null" != "$NAME" ] && append "$NAME"
        echo "DEBUG: in loop CMKVALUES=$CMKVALUES"
    done
    # WTF! CMKVALUES is now null but was fine just above!
   echo "DEBUG: out of loop CMKVALUES=$CMKVALUES"
}
mainloop

When I point this at (e.g.)
[ { "other":"a" },{ "name":"b" }, { "name":"c" }, { "name":"d" }

I get:
read null
DEBUG: in loop CMKVALUES=INIT
read b
DEBUG: in loop CMKVALUES=INIT,b
read c
DEBUG: in loop CMKVALUES=INIT,b,c
read d
DEBUG: in loop CMKVALUES=INIT,b,c,d
DEBUG: out of loop CMKVALUES=INIT

Somehow I appear to have created a sub shell inside the loop. However running the script below, the data entered in the loop is appended is still present outside of the loop?
DATA=""

function append()
{
   local s
   s=$1
   DATA="${DATA}${s}"
}
function mainloop()
{
   DATA="INIT:"
   while read i; do
      [ -n "$i" ] && append "$i"
      echo "Data is currently $DATA"
   done
   echo "Outside of loop Data is $DATA"
}
mainloop

e.g.
a
Data is currently INIT:a
b
Data is currently INIT:ab
c
Data is currently INIT:abc
Outside of loop Data is INIT:abc

Why do I loose the data in the first script but not in the second?

In the first version a belongs to other so it's skipped.  That's the easy one to catch.  In your second version [Data]starts as an empty array and has the values of the local variable s dumped into it.    In your first version CMKVALUES is only declared as a variable, not an array, and each read in the loop  is not moved because you haven't properly added to it, so it is staying at the initialized value.

erm, no. I wasn't expecting 'a' to be appended. I am NOT treating CMKVALUES as an array (and if I had been trying to append to an array I would not have got anything like this output). Issue was (as per reason for closing) that blah | while ... creates a subshell but (and I really don't understand why) while....done <$FILE does not.

See Section 3.2.3 of the Bash Manual, specifically the last paragraph RE: exit status for why this may be happening.

Also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9954/why-is-my-variable-being-localized-in-one-while-read-loop- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/677519/why-a-bash-array-remains-empty-if-i-pipe- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/143958/in-bash-read-after-a-pipe-is-not-setting-values  and cross https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78443452/variable-value-lost- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746553/read-values-into-a-shell-variable-from-a-pipe
