# output while loop in bash script

Tags: shell-script, shell

I have `ips` file with content:

```
192.168.10.10 3306
192.168.10.20 3306
```

and my script is:

```
1 #!/bin/bash
  2
  3 p=0
  4 cat /root/ips | while read host port
  5  do
  6    check_up=$(bash -c 'exec 3<> /dev/tcp/'$host'/'$port';echo $?' 2>/dev/null)
  7     if [ $check_up != 0 ]
  8         then
  9           p=$[$p+1]
 10           echo "(1):p in loop = $p"
 11     fi
 12         echo "(2):p in loop = $p"
 13  done
 14      echo "(3):p out loop = $p"
 15
 16     if [ $p % 2 != 0 ]
 17        then
 18             exit 1
 19      fi
~
```

and out put is:

```
[root@db1 ~]# ./new-script.sh
(1):p in loop = 1
(2):p in loop = 1
(1):p in loop = 2
(2):p in loop = 2
(3):p out loop = 0
./new-script.sh: line 16: [: too many arguments
```

why `echo "(3):p out loop = $p"` return `0` (first value `$p`)!? when last value `$p` is `2` ? also, how to fix the error in line 16?

Comment: Why do you believe that you're using correct `test` syntax?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams I did not understand you.what do you mean?

Comment: You're asking two questions - you should only ask one at a time, for the benefit of other people who search for answers before asking themselves. It becomes difficult for searches to find the correct url results when you combine questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to do arithmetic in the shell is `$((..))`. Standard `test`/`[` supports only comparisons and other tests. So, the standard-conforming version would be:

```
if [ "$(( p % 2 ))" -ne 0 ]; then...
```

<sup>(That only needs the quotes if your `IFS` contains digits, so usually they're not needed.)</sup>

---

In Bash/ksh/zsh, you could use the `(( .. ))` construct, which works like a command and allows the test too:

```
if (( p % 2 != 0 )); then ...
```

The `[[` test seems to allow some arithmetic, but it's a bit picky about the syntax/whitespace, so you probably shouldn't do that.

---

As for why the assignment to `p` doesn't persist outside the loop, see

- the question ["In bash, read after a pipe is not setting values"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/143958/170373)
- [BashFAQ 024: "I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)

Comment: Note that `[ p%2 -ne 0 ]` works in `ksh`.

Comment: And in `bash`.  `test` (and `[`) absolutely does do integer math if you actually use correct syntax, e. g. `if [ $((2+2)) -eq 4 ]; then echo yep; fi`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti, that's not `test` doing the addition, it's the arithmetic expansion that does it.

Comment: I should have said, rahter, that `[` and `test` can to integer arithmetic _comparison_ (with the `-eq`, `-ne`, `-ge`, `le`, `-lt`, and `-gt` operators).