# Entr: trying to trigger function while monitoring file change

Tags: bash, pipe, function

I'm trying to monitor some files with entr.

My script based on their examples:

```
do_it(){ echo Eita!; }
while true; do ls folder/* more-folder/* | entr -pd do_it; done
>> entr: exec do_it: No such file or directory
```

However, this works:

```
while true; do ls folder1/* folder2/* | entr -pd echo Eita!; done
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/143958/117549

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by the programmers of entr (https://github.com/eradman/entr/issues/6): "A function can be exported to a subshell, but you cannot execute a function with an external program. If you want to execute shell functions, you can write a loop such as this:"

```
do_it(){ echo 'Eita!'; }

while true; do
    ls folder1/* folder2/* | entr -pd -s 'kill $PPID'
    do_it
done
```

Answer (score 2):

The pipeline in your "while" loop runs in separate subshells. Since the `do_it` function is not exported, the child subshell on the right that runs `entr` does not know about it. The shortest solution would be to export the function (bash allows this).

```
do_it(){ echo Eita!; }
export -f do_it
while true; do ls folder/* more-folder/* | entr -pd do_it; done
```

If the `entr` command wants to execute something from disk, then I would suggest putting the function in a script file, then point `entr` to *that*.

#### file named /path/to/do_it

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Eita!
```

#### ensure the file is executable:

```
chmod +x /path/to/do_it
```

#### new commandline:

```
while true; do ls folder/* more-folder/* | entr -pd /path/to/do_it; done
```

Comment: Not working here... "entr: exec do_it: No such file or directory"

Comment: Some light? See: https://superuser.com/a/396652/88723

Comment: Apparently `entr` wants to find an executable in your path, and is unsatisfied with a bash function. I'll update my answer with something else to try.

Comment: Yes, it works. But the big question is: why with a function it is returning "entr: exec do_it: No such file or directory"? Everything I read points to the fact entr is using "exec".

Comment: By the programmers of entr: https://github.com/eradman/entr/issues/6