# Export environment variables parsed from YAML text file

Tags: environment-variables, yaml

I have some environment variables declared in a YAML file like:

```
runtime: python37

env_variables:
  API_URL: 'https://fake.api.com/'
  API_USERNAME: 'fake@email.com'
  API_PASSWORD: 'Passwooord'
```

I would like to export these to environment variables with a script, I can echo the correct syntax but I'm still unable to export them.

```
sed -nr '/env_variables:/,$ s/  ([A-Z_]+): (.*)/\1=\2/ p' app.yaml | while read assign; do echo $assign; done
```

This is different that [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/143958) as in my case the variable name is passed trough the pipe as well.

Comment: @muru in my case you also have variable names in the pipe, which is a step further from `read a b < <(echo 1 2 3 4 5)` where `a` and `b` are **after** the pipe. Could you please post a working case with my example?

Comment: What difference does that make? What part of it are you having trouble adapting to your case?

Comment: @muru the part where I assign to a variable whose name is in another variable — I'd be happy to accept your answer straight away if you post it below

Comment: `export "$name=$value"`, `printf -v "$name" "%s" "$value"`, `read "$name" <<<"$value"`, ... (Pick one)

Comment: I'm not near a PC, can't test an answer now. I can provide what I think should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `sed` command correctly outputs lines of the form `var=value`, you can do:

```
while read assign; do
 export "$assign"; 
done < <(sed -nr '/env_variables:/,$ s/  ([A-Z_]+): (.*)/\1=\2/ p' app.yaml)
```

Or, if you don't need to export, and the input is reasonably safe (no shell syntax),

```
. <(sed -nr '/env_variables:/,$ s/  ([A-Z_]+): (.*)/\1=\2/ p' app.yaml)
```

Comment: Thanks, the second works like a charm! The first works somehow, keeping quotes in the value of the variable, e.g. `echo $API_PASSWORD` prints `'Passwooord'`

Comment: The `sed` command needs to eliminate the quotes there (the shell doesn't interpret quotes after variable expansion) for the first.