# Using read, IFS and while together doubts

Tags: bash, read

I have a doubt because I understand that:

```
exec 0</etc/passwd
IFS=:
while read in USUARIO
do
    echo $USUARIO
done
```

output should be a list contining all system's users, instead of that I get the second row which is filled with x, when I want the first one; why?

Also, in this script you pass as argument a number and you see the list of user who have equal and more files than the value entered:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ( $# -eq 1) && ( $1==[0-9][0-9]* )]]
then
    echo "User with $1 files or more "
    cut -d':' -f1 /etc/passwd | while IFS= read -r USUARIO
    do
        if [[ $( find / -user $USUARIO -print | wc -l ) -ge $1 ]]
        then

            echo $USUARIO
        fi
    done
exit 0
else
    printf "Error: $0 int"
    exit 1
fi
```

and it works ok, but why it doesn't works:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ( $# -eq 1) && ( $1==[0-9][0-9]* )]]
then
    LIST="Users with more or $1 files: "
    cut -d':' -f1 /etc/passwd | while IFS= read -r USUARIO
    do
        if [[ $( find / -user $USUARIO -print | wc -l ) -ge $1 ]]
        then

            LIST="$LIST $USUARIO"
        fi
    done
echo $LIST
exit 0
else
    printf "Error $0 int"
    exit 1
fi
```

Its outputs is the raw string without appending user's names why?

Comment: AFAIK `read in USUARIO` assigns the *first* field to a variable named `in`

Comment: ... also see [Why is my variable local \[in\] one 'while read' loop, but not in another seemingly similar loop?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9954/why-is-my-variable-local-one-while-read-loop-but-not-in-another-seemingly-sim)

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have mixed up the syntax of `for` and `while`. `for` executes a sequence of commands for each element in a list; the syntax is `for VARIABLE in VALUES; do COMMANDS; done`: the keyword `in` separates the variable name from the list of values. `while` executes a sequence of commands while another sequence of commands is true; the syntax is `while COMMANDS; do COMMANDS; done`.

The command `read` reads one line and splits it into fields. The arguments of `read` are the variables to set the field values to. So `read in USUARIO` sets `in` to the first field and `USUARIO` to the second field, or if there are more than two fields (which is the case in your scenario) `USUARIO` is set to all the remaining fields (inner separators included). Each call to `read` reads a single line, and each loop iteration thus processes one line of the input.

Thus, to print the user names only, you need to write

```
while IFS=: read USUARIO rest
do
    echo "$USUARIO"
done
```

Regarding the second question (but next time, please don't ask unrelated questions together), the problem is that each command in a pipeline is executed in a subshell, so variables set in one of them aren't visible outside of the pipeline. See [Why is my variable local one 'while read' loop, but not in another seemingly similar loop?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9954/why-is-my-variable-local-one-while-read-loop-but-not-in-another-seemingly-sim)