# check duplicate login from file

Tags: shell-script, duplicate

I have a question about my code. I'm writing a `Bourne shell` script that get a user list from server by `who` command then put it into a file then, it will check the name by `read line` and if the script found a duplicate name it will print out a warning msg with the username, otherwise it will print out that no duplication found. Everything working as it should when the script found the duplicate name, but when  the script can not find any duplicate name it will not print anything, I know it is something to do with the last `if` statement but I try so many solutions but still stuck. If anyone have any suggestion please help me out. Really appreciated and answer in advance. ( see the code below )

```
    #!/bin/sh
    #who -u | sort -k1,5 > test3
    log=~/Desktop/test3
        while [ -f test ]; do
          while IFS= read line; do
           user=( $line )

            if [ "$olduser" = "${user[0]}" ]; then
              printf '\nThe user %s duplicated' "$olduser"
            fi

           olduser="${user[0]}"
          done<"$log"

            if [[ "$olduser" != "${user[0]}" ]]; then
              printf '\nNo duplication found.\n';
            fi


            #Testing store value                       
            #printf '\nolduser value = %s\n' "$olduser" 
           printf '\n=================================================================\n'
sleep 3
done
```

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Comment: @dessert Bourne shell, =)

Comment: I recommend [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net), for example for line 3 it outputs *[SC2039](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2039): In POSIX sh, arrays are undefined.* and in line 12 *In POSIX sh, [[ ]] is undefined* – if you really want to use `sh`, only use code it understands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code uses at least two things that standard `sh` does not support:

1. `[[ ... ]]`, this is an extension to the POSIX grammar that e.g. `bash` uses to introduce its own conditional expressions.
2. `user=( $line )`, this creates an array, which is another extension to the POSIX `sh`.

---

To find the duplicated lines in a text file:

```
sort file | uniq -d
```

`sort` will sort the input file and `uniq -d` will only output lines that occur multiple times in succession.

To use this on the output of `who` and only care about the user column (the first column):

```
who | awk '{ print $1 }' | sort | uniq -d
```

---

Using this in a script:

```
who | awk '{ print $1 }' | sort | uniq -d >duplicates.txt

if [ -s duplicates.txt ]; then
    echo 'The following dupes were found:'
    cat duplicates.txt
else
    echo 'No dupes'
fi
```

The `-s` test will be true for a non-empty file.

---

To do it manually in the shell, set a flag when you've found a duplicate:

```
dupe=0

who | awk '{ print $1 }' | sort -o users.txt

while IFS= read -r user; do
    if [ -n "$prev_user" ] && [ "$user" = "$prev_user" ]; then
        printf 'Duplication for "%s"\n' "$user"
        dupe=1
    fi

    prev_user=$user
done <users.txt

if [ "$dupe" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo 'No dupes'
fi
```

Comment: ok, i will give it a try, but then this command wont give me a duplicate user from who command right?

Comment: @PrinPuyakul I'm not sure what command you refer to or what you mean.

Comment: i mean `who | awk '{ print $1 }' | sort | uniq -d`,  sorry for my bad English communication skill haha

Comment: @PrinPuyakul That command should give you the duplicated usernames that the `who` command outputs.

Comment: So `var=$(who | awk '{ print $1 }' | sort | uniq -d); [ "$var" ] && printf "\\nThe user %s is duplicated." $var || printf "\\nNo duplication found.\\n"` does what your loop was supposed to do.

Comment: @dessert, I see, thanks so much for your answer i will try to understand how it work ^^",

Comment: @Kusalananda ok, I will try those out and let u know the result, thanks a lot for your help again ^^:

Comment: @Kusalananda 
 
I tested the script its working ok but `if [ "$dupe" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo 'No dupes' fi` it always get execute ?_? 
And another question I would like to ask, if i want to insert the result from who | awk '{ print $1 }' | sort in to a file and do the check from that file. how do i achieve that? do i just `who | awk '{ print $1 }' | sort > list` then at the end of the while loop i just `done < list` or i just only need `done < list` at the end? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: @PrinPuyakul I had two errors in the last bit of code that I now have fixed. A test was inverted (leftover from an edit), and the test on `"$dupe" -ne 1` would always  be true, as you pointed out (I fell into [this trap](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9954/why-is-my-variable-local-one-while-read-loop-but-not-in-another-seemingly-sim), because I was running the code in `ksh93` rather than `sh` or `bash`). I've updated the code to write to a temporary file. Sorry for any confusion!

Comment: @Kusalananda No worry! you are always help out and i always learn something from you ! thanks a lot for your help, I will explain my knowledge into other script as well so know I will know the different from syntax like you and dessert point out about `[[  ]]` syntax