# Variable inherited in the subshell without exporting in the main shell

Tags: shell, pipe, subshell

I am having the below shell script

```
var="this is a test"

ls -ltr| while read file
do
     echo $var
done
echo $var
```

I am getting the below output:

```
this is a test
this is a test
this is a test
```

How am I getting the value of the variable "var" set to "this is a test" inside while loop since piping will spawn a new sub-shell and I am also not exporting my "var" variable in the main shell?

As far as I know, in order for the child to inherit the variable values from the parent shell, we need to export the variable, but in this case the variable value is getting inherited without the "export" statement.

Comment: In particular, [jsbillings' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9955/117549)

Comment: subshells get copies of all variables, not only the exported ones, but that really has nothing to do with getting variables _out_ of the different kinds of `while` structures, which is what that other Q is really about

Comment: @ilkkachu "subshells get copies of all variables". I am not agree. Subshell get only environment variables and for putting the ordinary shell variable to the environment, we need the `export` command.

Comment: @MiniMax, subshells do. normal commands don't.

Comment: @ilkkachu But the each part of a pipeline is running in the own subshell. So, in this case, the `ls -ltr` and `while` runs each in the own subshell. Thus, they see only environment variables.

Comment: @MiniMax: No, as this question shows, the `while` loop gets a copy of the local (non-exported) `var` variable, which is defined before the pipeline.  Similar thing would happen if the left hand side of the pipe was something like `if true; then echo "$var"; var=quick; echo "The $var brown fox"; fi`.

Comment: @G-Man Why in this case this code works? - `true | sed '' <<< $var`. The `sed` is not builtin command, but it also prints the value of the `$var`. How it knows this value in the subshell? I think, that the expansion occurs in the parent shell and the `sed` get the value of the `$var`. I have elaborated this thought in the answer.

Comment: @BLayer Yes, I think the same :)

Comment: Had a related question a while back: https://askubuntu.com/q/704154/295286 Might be useful

Comment: @MiniMax:  If you understand now that you were confused,  you can also delete your comments that reflect that confusion.

Comment: @G-Man I think it is useful discussion. Someone can have same thoughts. Or you think it is confusing?

Answer (score 6):

Let's see what the Bash manual says ([3.7.3 Command Execution Environment](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Execution-Environment.html#Command-Execution-Environment))

> The shell has an execution environment, which consists of the
>   following:
>
> - **shell parameters that are set by variable assignment** or with set or inherited from the shell’s parent in the environment
> - shell functions defined during execution or inherited from the shell’s parent in the environment
>
> Command substitution, commands grouped with parentheses, and
>   asynchronous commands are invoked in a **subshell environment that is
>   a duplicate of the shell environment** [...]
>
> Changes made to the subshell environment cannot affect the shell’s execution environment.

In [3.2.2 Pipelines](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html#index-pipeline), it's also said

> Each command in a pipeline is executed in its own subshell

<sup>(Of course that only applies to multi-command pipelines)</sup>

So, the parts of a pipeline, as well as other subshells, get copies of *all* the shell variables, but any changes to them are *not* visible to the outside shell.

With other commands, you still need to `export`:

> When a simple command other than a builtin or shell function is to be
>   executed, it is invoked in a separate execution environment that
>   consists of the following.
>
> - **shell variables and functions marked for export**, along with variables exported for the command, passed in the environment

---

Food for thought: what does this print?

```
bash -c 'f() { echo "$a $b"; }; a=1; b=1; (b=2; f); f'
```

Comment: Well done! I have grasped just now, that my version can't be true, because the shell should left all variable names unsubstituted for the `while` loop, else how the `while` loop will do parameter expansion of inner variables in the each iteration? I will delete my answer - it's wrong.