# Bash: child process and pipelining

Tags: bash, pipe, echo

The purpose of my script is to count how many lines there are in a `file`. I know I could use `wc` for example but the purpose of this exercise is to understand processes and pipelines in Linux.

The script executed on my terminal:

`C=0; cat file | while read line ; do C=$[ $C + 1 ] ; done ; echo $C`

I always get `0` or whatever number I inizialize `C` variable.

In my textbook they explain this behavior saying that for every pipeline a new child process is created, it inherits all father variables but when the child dies the father still "see" his old values. And I'm ok with that.

What I don't understand is that I only see one pipeline, between `C=0; cat file` and `while read line ; do C=$[ $C + 1 ] ; done ; echo $C`. So I'm guessing that the second part is executed by the child (`echo` too) so why it prints the wrong value? Shouldn't the child increase `C` variable AND print the correct value as it belongs to the same pipe?

Comment: As a side note, shell variables should be lower-case. Environment variables should be upper-case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I don't understand is that I only see one pipeline, between `C=0; cat file` and `while read line ; do C=$[ $C + 1 ] ; done ; echo $C`.

No, that's not how it parses. You actually have three "pipelines":

```
C=0
cat file | while read line ; do C=$[ $C + 1 ] ; done
echo $C
```

(Granted, the first and the third are degenerate single-command pipelines, but technically they still are just that. A pipeline is [a sequence of *one or more* commands separated by the control operator '|'](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02))

In other words, the first and last semicolons separate pipelines. The ones between `while` and `done` don't, since they're a part of the `while` [compound command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04).

A simpler example without any compound commands:

```
$ echo hello | tr a-z x ; echo you | tr a-z y
xxxxx
yyy
```

Here, we can easily see that only `hello` goes to the first `tr`, and only `you` goes to the second `tr`, i.e. the semicolon separates the pipelines.

The question [Why is my variable local in one 'while read' loop, but not in another seemingly similar loop?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9954/170373) contains a number of ways of doing what you tried to do, to be able to output the value of `C` as updated by the loop.