# rename directories containing left/right square

Tags: shell-script, rename, nemo

To rename directories containing left & right squares you can use:

```
shopt -s globstar 
rename -n 's/\(|\[|\]|\)//g' **
```

This will rename everything with [ & ] from the directory you're in and recursive..

but I need to execute this as a nemo.action script, and can't get it to work.
*(Basically a normal bash script)*

My current script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar 

rename  "$@" 's/\(|\[|\]|\)//g' **
```

where `$@` is `/media/sf_Mediaserver3/Untitled Folder/[ hdjue] [kskk]`

where the `[ hdjue] [kskk]` *(just random letters)* is the starting folder that I want to rename and the following files/folders...

This doesn't work of course, and now I have to go to the parent directory and run the first lines, but that would process ALL directories in the parent directory, not only the
`[ hdjue] [kskk]`  anybody got any idea how to solve this?

it almost seems like the rename function can't handle a start directory?

And if possible, remove all spaces (replace with . (dot)), and make the filename/directory lowercase, to simplify the compatibility with external/internal requests..

Comment: Sure not, why should it, but can't you simply `cd` to it?  `cd "$@" && rename 's/...//'` ?

Comment: @pLumo by using cd I'm in the directory I want to rename, that don't work..

Comment: The script should accept an argument that's a directory, and then rename not only that directory but also all its files and subdirectories (recursively)? And the rename operation is simply to get rid of `[` and `]` characters from the file names?

Comment: I think `rename  "$@" 's/\(|\[|\]|\)//g' **` where `"$@"` expands to filename(s)/pathname(s) makes no sense. Pathnames must be at the end.

Comment: In my Ubuntu (Larry Wall's) `rename` *can* rename the current directory. But its name must be supplied with characters you want to match. This means `rename … ./` is futile while `rename … "$(pwd -P)"` is often the right way. Does this information advance your research?

Comment: @Kamil I forgot to mention that I'm a newbie, $(pwd -P)??   the path last didn't work, but Roaima's solution worked great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requirement here, as I understand it, is to remove all instances of the `[` and `]` characters from files and directories at and under the specified paths.

The difficulty is to avoid renaming the directory while it's still being traversed. The globstar `**` lists items from the root down rather than depth first, so given an example such as `a` `a/b` `a/b/c`, renaming `a` will mean that the paths to `a/b` and `a/b/c` are no longer valid. The `find` option can handle this with its `-depth`, but that requires a different approach

```
#!/bin/bash
#
find "$@" -depth -name '*[[\]]*' -print0 |
    while IFS= read -d '' -r item
    do
        path="${item%/*}" file="${item##*/}"    # Separate path and file name parts
        name="${file//[[\]]/}"                  # Generate new file name
        name="${name// /.}"                     # Comment: space becomes dot
        name="${name,,}"                        # Comment: lowercase name

        echo mv -f "$item" "$path/$name"        # Rename
    done
```

Remove `echo` (or supplement it) when you are happy the script will do what you expect.

I've used `-print0` in conjunction with the `-d ''` option for `read` to handle files with really strange filenames (including those with newlines and non-printing characters). You can remove both if you want to see what is going on - or if your implementations don't support them - but the script then becomes less robust

The modifiers when assigning the variables `path`, `file`, and `name` match using globs (not regular expressions). A single modifier (`%`, `#`, `/`) means a shortest or single match; a double modifier (`%%`, `##`, `//`) means a longest match or multiple matches. It is all documented in the `bash` man page but here is my explanation with context:

- `${item%/*}` The `%` indicates that the *shortest* match to the glob pattern should be removed from the *end* of the value of `$item`. So for `a/b/c` we would remove text matching `/*` leaving `a/b`
- `${item##*/}` The `##` indicates that the *longest* match to the glob pattern should be removed from the *beginning* of the value of `$item`. So for `a/b/c` we would remove text matching `*/` leaving `c`
- `${file//[[\]]/}` The `//` indicates that *multiple* replacements of the glob should be replaced with the text following the next `/`, i.e. nothing. The glob is a square-bracketed collection of the two characters `[` and `]`, meaning "either `[` or `]`". So for `ab[cd]ef[gh` we would end up with `abcdefgh`

Comment: wow, that worked, not that I fully understand how it exactly works, it was took me a full day to find why my other script that removes spaces and puts . instead, and that was because the filenames had [ ] in them..    if I understand this correctly, it only runs the renaming code if the directory or filename has a [ or a ] in it?

Comment: @JoBe I remember your previous question. The code there might misbehave for filenames with `[` and/or `]` because you didn't quote the variable properly. This leads me to a hypothesis: you keep "fixing" filenames by removing troublesome characters because you want some flawed scripts/commands to work without errors. I may be wrong. But *if* I'm right then you should rather concentrate on fixing the scripts/commands.

Comment: @Kamil actually in trying to write a massive script that processes movies, subtitles, auto renaming and making them compatible with my media system, my next work after solving this is to make it check if the subtitles are duplicates.. oh, I'm also using gio to set the folder icons with country flags depending on what subtitles it has (works good), but as I have written in my profile, I'm dyslexic, and unfortunately beginning to show signs of dementia, so sometimes I can write a code, and the next day don't understand how it works (do a lot of comments nowadays) - a programmers hell..

Comment: @roaima well, file//[[\]]/} for example, I suspect it's regex? don't fully understand ${item##*/} , the ## (if you see my answer to Kamil you might understand why I'm having issues)

Comment: @JoBe It's OK. I can imagine a media system that doesn't fully support some characters in filenames (and you cannot fix it easily). I just wanted to make sure your need for renaming is not solely because of flawed scripts.

Comment: @Kamil nope, just trying my best with my knowledge to get it to work, appreciating the help

Comment: @roaima Thanks for the extra information, now I understand better!

Comment: @roaima  I actually got a follow-up question, I assume it always renames the first directory last (otherwise it would crash), but  I need to put the first directory's new name to a variable (if I want to implant this script into another),  and in the last loop, the $name contains the new name, but it seems to clear the variables when existing the loop, so $name is empty, is there anyway to keep that variable intact?

Comment: You [can't do that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9954/100397), unfortunately, but I can't see a reason why you shouldn't be able to regenerate the modified initial filenames from the values in `"$@"`

Comment: @roaima Ok, I did a quick-solution, and just saved the variable to a temporary file and then I just read it back to a variable outside the loop..

Comment: @roaima hm, I'm having issues, it renames the directory but not the files inside it?

Comment: Example please, @JoBe

Comment: @roaima the script you wrote, are having issues renaming files with more than one [ ]

Comment: .. but it does work. but sometimes it doesn't.. I've got to investigate a little more..

Comment: @JoBe `file='ab[cd]ef[gh'; echo "${file//[[\]]/}"` works exactly as expected for me - all three instances of a square bracket get removed

Comment: @roaima yes, don't really know what's the issue, it works most of the time (unless there's a ' in the filename)

Comment: My code doesn't care about single quote characters in filenames

Comment: oops, my bad, I added `if  [[ $jdir =~ [']['] ]] ` as a pre-check to see if it was necessary to run your rename code, but I missed that it don't detects if any files have ][ , it only checked the first directory.. as I wrote earlier I'm not so good at this, so when I'm removing the ][, removing the space and adding . between the words, and when I'm renaming it all to lowercase, is 3 different function, since I can't make it in one.. so it was my mistake, I messed it up.. as usual..

Comment: @JoBe if you wanted to remove square brackets, replace spaces with dots, and lowercase the result why didn't you say so? Answer amended

Comment: @roaima oh, gee, thanks a lot. I didn't mention it because I already had "solved" that issue, not effective, but manageable, and I didn't want to ask for to much, since I've seen that if you're asking for a complete solution, people normally don't help, since they think you're "lazy", and at least need to try... But now when I see your solution, I understand how it works, and should be able to use it and develope it as I see fit.. hopefully.. and again, I really appreciate the help.. (I'll update the question to include the last update from you)

Comment: @roaima BUT! I just realised that that code only runs it the filename/directory has ] [ in the name, can that be changed to run on all filenames/directories?

Comment: Remove the name criterion from `find` so that the loop runs for everything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111911/discussion-between-roaima-and-jobe).