# esx busybox shell script, reading line by line from a variable using while

Tags: busybox

I have a big file called `file1` on my ESX host. I run some `awk` command on the file and extract useful blocks of data into a variable which works fine on the busybox shell.

Now I want to read from that variable (`info`) line by line, change something and write to a different file.

```
info=$(awk '/pat1/{flag=1}/pat2/{flag=0}flag' file1)  -> works fine

while IFS= read -r line; do 

    printf '%s\n' "$line" 

done <<< "$info"
```

but the while loop doesn't work. Get error as "unexpected redirection".
I also tried `done << "$info". Then I get error as

syntax error: unexpected end of file (expecting "}")

So basically how to read from a variable line by line?

Thanks
Would appreciate your response

Comment: Correct formatting please, thx.

Comment: What's the content of `info`?

Answer (score 0):

The here-string redirection `<<<` isn't a standard feature, and Busybox's sh doesn't support it. The error message is a bit odd, but perhaps it parses it as `<<` followed by `<`. Also the here-doc syntax, started by `<<` is a different thing completely.

You'll have to do something like

```
echo "$info" | while IFS= read -r line; do 
    printf '%s\n' "$line" 
done
```

Or pass the data through a temporary file:

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
awk '/pat1/{flag=1}/pat2/{flag=0}flag' file1 > "$tmpfile"
while IFS= read -r line; do 
    printf '%s\n' "$line" 
done < "$tmpfile"
rm "$tmpfile"
```

But see [Why is my variable local in one 'while read' loop, but not in another seemingly similar loop?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9954/170373) if you use the first one.