# Export not setting variable when piping it to other command

Tags: bash, pipe, environment-variables

When piping export into another command (using bash 3.2), the variable does not get changed.

```
export USER=new | cat ; env | grep USER
```

Output: `USER=old`

The User variable does not get changed and stays the same.
But export successfully exited: `export USER=new | echo $?` outputs 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, the parts of a pipeline (except the last one in some shells) run in subshells, that is, the shell forks a copy of itself for each of them, and then each copy processes the command in that part and executes any external commands (like `cat` there). The main shell that continues with the next command (the other pipeline) doesn't see the changed value.

(And in any case, what would you expect the value of `var` should be after a command like `var=foo | var=bar`?)

Usually this comes up when you have variable assignments in the last part of a pipeline, like

```
n=0
some command | while read line; do n=$((n+1)); done
```

which would leave `n` set to `0` in many shells, but not in all: ksh and zsh run the last part in the main shell, and Bash has an option for that. This is discussed in [Why is my variable local in one 'while read' loop, but not in another seemingly similar loop?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9954/170373).

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the code on this way:

```
export USER=new
env | grep $USER
```

To get the content of variable `USER` you need `$` before. And pipe on `export` is meaningless as `export` command do not have any output to STDOUT