Bash: export does not work if preceeds a pipe redirection
Example 1 (export and tee):
$ export var=1 | tee /dev/null
$ echo $var
$

Example 2 (null command between export and pipe):
$ export var=1 && : | tee /dev/null
$ echo $var
1

export sets var only if there is an intermediate command between export and pipe.
The problem seems to be in the pipe, because I reproduced this not only with "tee" command, but also with "xargs echo" for example.
Why?

export is a shell builtin, not a command. If you execute it in a subshell, the exported variable's definition vanishes when the subshell exits.

in the first invocation :  export var=1 | tee /dev/null will be launched as a subshell by your shell, because it needs to attach together the stdout/stdin because of the pipe : and that subshell will briefly have an environnement variable var set to 1, but the calling shell will not get this when the subshell finished. In the second, you export var=1 in the current shell, and-then you launch a : | tee /dev/null in a subshell.

So, the difference in the second invocation is that the pipe operator (and therefore the creation of the child shell as a consequence) applies only to the second command right from &&. Thank you, @OlivierDulac! I agree that my question is duplicate and answered also in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/675043/302420.
