# Why wait in this script is not executed after all subshells?

Tags: subshell, wait

In this script, that pulls all git repositories:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

find / -type d -name .git 2>/dev/null | 
while read gitFolder; do
    if [[ $gitFolder == *"/Temp/"* ]]; then
        continue;
    fi
    if [[ $gitFolder == *"/Trash/"* ]]; then
        continue;
    fi
    if [[ $gitFolder == *"/opt/"* ]]; then
        continue;
    fi
    parent=$(dirname $gitFolder);
    echo "";
    echo $parent;
    (git -C $parent pull && echo "Got $parent") &
done 
wait
echo "Got all"
```

the `wait` does not wait for all `git pull` subshells.

Why is it so and how can I fix it?

Comment: It's unlikely, but still possible, that one of your paths contains a newline at some point in time. And that will break your `read`. Using `find … | ` is practically newer a good way of dealing with these things. Also, it feels very awkward that instead of specifying the directories you actually want to search in you exclude some. Congratulations for searching `/sys/` and `/dev/`  and `/var/run/` … for git repos!

Comment: @MarcusMüller The issue is that the background tasks are associated with the subshell at the end of the pipe. Puttting tho `wait` in the same subshell helps.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, thanks for notifying me about those directories. I will exclude them.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati that's the **opposite** I've wanted to achieve. instead of excluding directories, you should search only these that you care for (instead of `/`, which really makes no sense).

Comment: As [they's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/688214/170373) says, this is similar to [Why is my variable local in one 'while read' loop, but not in another seemingly similar loop?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9954/170373). The answers there have some other workarounds.

Comment: Marcus, when we become dynamic, there is no "inclusive" approach unless you configure stuff. Thus we search everywhere, *that makes sense*. A gir repo might be cloned inside the root, or in home, or in any other place. If I give you my laptop, how do you know where are my git clones?

Comment: Also re. `read line`, if you do that, you probably want `IFS= read -r line` instead, see [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123/170373). (Still only matters if your filenames are naughty.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The issue is that the `wait` is run by the wrong shell process. In `bash`, each part of a pipeline is running in a separate subshell. The background tasks belong to the subshell executing the `while` loop. Moving the `wait` into that subshell would make it work as expected:

```bsh
find ... |
{
    while ...; do
        ...
        ( git -C ... && ... ) &
    done
    wait
}

echo 'done.'
```

You also have some [unquoted variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694).

I would get rid of the pipe entirely and instead run the loop from `find` directly, [which gets rid of the need to parse the output from `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697).

```bsh
find / -type d -name .git \
    ! -path '*/Temp/*' \
    ! -path '*/opt/*' \
    ! -path '*/Trash/*' \
    -exec sh -c '
    for gitpath do
        git -C "$gitpath"/.. pull &
    done
    wait' sh {} +
```

Or, using `-prune` to avoid even entering any of the subdirectories we don't want to deal with,

```bsh
find / \( -name Temp -o -name Trash -o -name opt \) -prune -o \
    -type d -name .git -exec sh -c '
    for gitpath do
        git -C "$gitpath"/.. pull &
    done
    wait' sh {} +
```

---

As mentioned in comments, you could also use `xargs` to have greater control over the number of concurrently running `git` processes.  The `-P` option (for specifying the number of concurrent tasks) used below is non-standard, as are `-0` (for reading `\0`-delimited pathnames) and `-r` (for avoiding running the command when there's no input).  GNU `xargs` and some other implementations of this utility have these options though.  Also, the `-print0` predicate of `find` (to output `\0`-delimited pathnames) is non-standard, but commonly implemented.

```bsh
find / \( -name Temp -o -name Trash -o -name opt \) -prune -o \
    -type d -name .git -print0 |
xargs -t -0r -P 4 -I {} git -C {}/.. pull
```

I'm sure GNU `parallel` could also be used in a similar way, but since this is not the main focus of this question I'm not pursuing that train of thought.

Comment: perfect. Thank you so much. That solved the issue, and I also learnt some new concepts.

Comment: See also GNU `xargs`'s `-P` to have more control on how many jobs are started in parallel `xargs -rt0P10 -I% -a <(find ... -printf '%h\0') git -C % pull`