# In Bash why echo hello | read myvar && echo $myvar doesn't output? Zsh works fine

Tags: bash, pipe

I quite don't understand why Bash would not hold the value of `myvar` in this example.

```
 echo hello | read myvar && echo $myvar
```

I would understand if I were running that command as two separate commands, then the scope of the variable would not exist for the second line.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe processes run in a sub-shell, and it is impossible for child processes to affect the environment of their parent (and their own environment goes away when the child process terminates).  In your example, the `read myvar` is run in a sub-shell - myvar is set, but does not (can not) propagate back to the parent shell which runs both `echo` statements.

You'll need to use a here string or redirection and [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) instead of a pipe.  For example:

Here string:

```
$ read myvar <<<"hello" && echo $myvar
hello
```

The string can be a fixed string or variable(s) or a combination of both:

```
$ read myvar <<<"Hello $USER, your home is $HOME" && echo $myvar
Hello cas, your home is /home/cas
```

Redirection and process substitution:

```
$ read myvar < <(echo hello) && echo $myvar
hello
```

---

See also:
[Why is my variable local in one 'while read' loop, but not in another seemingly similar loop?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9954/why-is-my-variable-local-in-one-while-read-loop-but-not-in-another-seemingly)

Comment: Another way is: `echo hello | { read myvar; echo $myvar; }`

Comment: Yeah, but that still doesn't affect the parent process running `echo hello`.  Try running `echo $myvar` again after that pipeline finishes.  The `{ read myvar; echo $myvar; }` group command is run in the sub-shell created by the pipe.  See `man bash`, search for Compound Commands.  Also search for Pipelines.