# Pipe with loops in shell script

Tags: shell-script, files

I have a text file with this information:

```
Game Copies_Sold(M) Release_date Genre   
God_of_War 19 20/04/2018 Action-Adventure 
Uncharted_4 16 10/05/2016 Action-adventure 
Spider-Man 13 07/09/2018 Action-adventure  
The_Witcher_3 10 18/05/2015 Action_role-playing
```

and I need to sum the numbers of the second column, so I wrote this script:

```
#!/bin/bash                                           
file=$1                                                   
s=0                                                      
tail -n +2 $file |cut -f 2 |                                
{ while read line                                          
do                                                      
s=$(( $s+$line ))                                        
done <$file }                                            
echo $s
```

but obviously I do something wrong. What's to be done here? Thank you!

Comment: Related: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Comment: [Why is my variable local in one 'while read' loop, but not in another seemingly similar loop?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9954/170373)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be something like:

```
#! /bin/sh -
file=${1?}
awk 'NR >= 2 {sum += $2}; END {print sum+0}' < "$file"
```

Problems with your approach:

- you do not check whether at least one argument is passed to your script (addressed here crudely with `${1?}`).
- Missing quotes around `$file`
- Missing `--` for `tail` to mark the end of options (nitpick: and same [`-` in the shebang](/q/351729))
- default separator for `cut` is TAB, while your input looks like it's space separated. For `awk` default separator is any amount of blanks (including space and tab).
- You're piping to the loop, but also redirecting that loop's input from `$file`.
- Missing `;` or newline before `}`
- Missing `-r` option to `read`
- In bash, the right-most component of a pipeline also runs in a subshell (unless the `lastpipe` option is enabled), so changes to the `$s` variable after that pipeline returns would be lost.
- but first [you're using a shell loop to process text which in general is bad practice, inefficient and hard to get right](/q/169716).
- here it's worse as you're [using shell arithmetic on external input which introduces command injection vulnerabilities in bash](/q/172103).
- there's nothing bash-specific in your script, so you can remove the bash dependency by changing the shebang to use the system's `sh`.

Several of those mistakes would have been spotted by [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) (also available as standalone software you can install on your system).

Here, it gives:

```
$ shellcheck myscript
 
Line 4:
tail -n +2 $file |cut -f 2 |                                
           ^-- SC2086 (info): Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086)
tail -n +2 "$file" |cut -f 2 |                                
 
Line 5:
{ while read line                                          
        ^-- SC2162 (info): read without -r will mangle backslashes.
 
Line 7:
s=$(( $s+$line ))                                        
^-- SC2030 (info): Modification of s is local (to subshell caused by pipeline).
      ^-- SC2004 (style): $/${} is unnecessary on arithmetic variables.
         ^-- SC2004 (style): $/${} is unnecessary on arithmetic variables.
 
Line 8:
done <$file }                                            
      ^-- SC2086 (info): Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086)
done <"$file" }                                            
 
Line 9:
echo $s
     ^-- SC2031 (info): s was modified in a subshell. That change might be lost.
```

Comment: In most `awk` versions you may not need `'NR > 2` because `awk` will interpret the string as zero

Comment: @RomeoNinov, true but only as long as the header for that second column doesn't  start with something that looks like a number. For instance, if that were `Infamous_Copies_Sold(M)`, you'd get `inf` or `+inf` on output because that string starts with `Inf` which is taken as the infinity floating point number. Best it to skip that first line if it's not meant to be counted.