# Understanding bash read variable substitution

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe

First of all, I have little experience using Bash and I apologize for my bad English.
Maybe it's obvious.

I am trying to understand why Bash drop value of the variable in this oneliner.

`echo "Alpha;Beta;Gamma" |  IFS=";" read First Second Third; echo $First $Second $Third`

no output

But

`echo "Alpha;Beta;Gamma" |  (IFS=";" read First Second Third; echo $First $Second $Third)`

has the right output

`Alpha Beta Gamma`.

I guess the `read` command opens a subshell and when it is close the variables lose their values.

If I am right, how to prevent it?

The goal was to separate a CSV like structure into variables.

Thanks in advice!

BR,

b

Comment: Thank you for the hint! Partially yes, because there is no loop at all. And I expect that the last pipe will be executed in the parent shell, therefore the variables would be defined there and keep their value.

Comment: In the meantime i dug up some info from this toppic [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9954/why-is-my-variable-local-in-one-while-read-loop-but-not-in-another-seemingly). This type of redirection is working `while read var ; do x=55 ; done < <(echo fred)
echo "$x"`. But I don't understand why.

Comment: The last command in a pipeline is *not* executed in the parent shell (unless you [set the `lastpipe` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) -- but it's not set by default). Whether that last command is a `while` loop or a simple command like `read` does not matter. As for why the `done < <(echo fred)` version works, it's because that's not a pipe, so the `while` loop isn't forced into a subshell.

Comment: _"I guess the read command opens a subshell and when it is close the variables lose their values."_, it's not `read`, but the pipeline. True, `read` is one to naturally appear in cases like this, but see Gilles' example of `a=0; a=1 | a=2; echo $a` in [their answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9994/170373) to the `while read` question.

Comment: @ilkkachu That is my problem exactly. The last part (right side of the pipe) lose the value. In the example it keeps it. That is what confuse me.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I have tried with the lastpipe also, but the result was the same.

Comment: @bas1c, the difference between `a | b; c` and `a | (b; c)` is that in the second one, the right-hand side of the pipeline contains the whole group in parenthesis. You can do that, but in some cases you might need to put basically the whole remainder of the script within that group, which might be a bit awkward.

Comment: @bas1c Correction: you need to set `lastpipe` *and* disable job control, so run `shopt -s lastpipe; set +m` and then retry your test.